# Rails timezones VS MySQL timezones

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

In my Rails (3.0) application, I use timezones using the helper **time_zone_select()**.
It generates timezone names like "(GMT+01:00) Paris"...

But these names are different from those in MySQL, where the same timezone would be "Europe/Paris".

How can I convert Rails timezones to MySql ones ?

The tricky part is that for several reasons I *have* to use the default Rails helper, and in my models I *have* to use the MySQL timezones.
So I can't use Ruby timezones in my models, and I can't use a list of MySQL timezones instead of the Rails helper...
I really need a way to convert from the first to the latter.

Any idea?

**Edit:** I'm currently trying to use ActiveSupport::TimeZone[**(ruby_timezone)**].tzinfo.name, is there a better way?

Comment: Your way seems right to me, though I would possibly worry about Rails supporting timezones that MySQL doesn't...

Comment: Romain: yes, I am wondering the same thing... I think I'm going to test each one with a *for each* loop.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I finally found a way :

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[ruby_timezone].tzinfo.name
```

Romain suggested there may be some Rails timezones not supported by MySQL, so I tested the following in the console, and the answer is: they all work :)

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.each do |ruby_timezone|
  mysql_timezone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[ruby_timezone.name].tzinfo.name
  puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select convert_tz('2011-01-01 00:00:00', 'UTC', '#{mysql_timezone}')").first
  end
end
```

If a timezone was not supported by MySQL, it would have returned nil.

I don't know if there is a better way, but at least it works :)